# iOS - Is there a programmatically way to create multiple windows that don't split the screen?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ipados, uiscene

I'm using UIScenes and SwiftUI to create a simple app.

I need to create multiple windows programmatically, but not with the same design outcome from requestSceneSessionActivation, that splits the screen into 2 pieces. I need the other one, like the image... [image]

I didn't find anything in the UIScene documentation for it.
If you know a way to close it too, it would be awesome!

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: @matt unittest and automation tests...

Comment: Good answer! I didn’t think of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately `UISceneActivationRequestOptions` (passed to `requestSceneSessionActivation`) doesn't provide an option to specify how the new scene should be presented. Oddly there is a `UIWindowSceneDestructionRequestOptions` class for indicating how a scene can be dismissed. There should be a `UIWindowSceneActivationRequestOptions` class that allows you specify how it is shown. I suggest filing an enhancement request with Apple using the Feedback app on iOS 13.

Closing a scene can be done using `UIApplication requestSceneSessionDestruction`.

Comment: Thank you @rmaddy! I opened the feedback request... Let's see if I get any answer any time soon.

Comment: @CarlaCamargo Don't expect an answer ever. They will either add it in some future version of iOS or they won't. But you will never get a reply.

Comment: iOS 15 introduced UIWindowScene.ActivationRequestOptions with the option .prominent -- still not quite what you want.